# How do I use array and MACRO to create a survey that tells the Rating and Number of Responses in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that uses MACROS and arrays. It asks to enter a any rating 1-10 and creates a chart.
 Rating Responses 
   10      25 
   9       50 
   8       100 
    ... ... 
  -1239    0
ect.
I am coming across a large amount of syntax errors and cant figure out how to get this code to run completely.  bellow is what I came up with. does anyone know what I can fix to make the output come out correctly using this general code idea that I started. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_RESPONDANTS 20;
#define MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE 0; 
#define MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE 10;
#define TERMINATOR -1;
int main(void)
{
const int RESPONSE_VALUES = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE - MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE
int value;
int loopCount;

// enter rating 1-10

    printf ("Please enter a value between %d and %d. Use %d to end input: \n    ", MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE, MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE, TERMINATOR);
//printf("Please enter a value between %d and %d. Use %d to end input: ",      "%d", MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE);

int ratingCounters[RESPONSE_VALUES] = { 0 };

// loopCount, responses[MAX_RESPONDANTS]; value;

for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < MAX_RESPONDANTS)
{
    scanf("%d", &value);
    ratingCounters[loopCount] = value;    
}

if (value > MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE && value <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE)
{
    printf("response is","%d" ,RESPONSE_VALUES);
}
else if (value = TERMINATOR)    
{
   printf("Outside valid range. Please input another number.\n");
}

printf("\n\nRating Number of Responses\n");
printf("------ --------------------\n");

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When posting questions regarding build errors, please include, in the body of the question, the actual errors including any informational notes, complete and unedited. But before that, try to actually *read* the error messages, try to understand what they mean. Most compilers are very good at telling you exactly what the problem is, and sometimes even tells you what to do to solve the problems. The error message also contains line numbers, telling you exactly where to look. Start from the top of the error messages, and fix them one at a time, and rebuild between.

Comment: Also, once you fixed your build errors, and actually can run the program, you will have *undefined behavior* as you index the `ratingCounters` array out of bounds. You declare it to contain 10 elements, but then write up to element 20. There are also other logical errors, like you checking for valid input *after* you're done reading the input.

Comment: yes they are basically errors that are saying i am needing parenthesis, but there is no need for them is some spots.

Comment: C can easily have so called *follow up error* to earlier errors. That's why I recommend you simply start with the first error, fix it, and the rebuild. Fixing one single error can mean many follow-up errors are fixed as well. Things like missing semicolons or braces can really screw up a lot of code following the actual error, giving you many errors that doesn't really exist.

Comment: this is my first error line      printf ("Please enter a value between %d and %d. Use %d to end input: \n ", MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE, MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE, TERMINATOR);   and i cant get the most simple error (Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before ',' out.. any idea?

Comment: Your definition of `RESPONSE_VALUES` seems to be missing the `;` at the end. A typical example where you would have learned a lot by producing a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: when posting additions/corrections to the question, edit the question in the question itself, do not post updates in the comments.

Comment: when coding, please indent consistently.  This means indent after EVERY opening brace '{'  and unIndent before every closing brace '}'.  One notable result is, for a function, the only lines on the left margin are the function signature and the first opening brace, and the last closing brace.

Comment: in C, the use of `const` to define a variable on the stack is not a good idea as it consumes stack space and the execution of the code requires extra code to fetch the value from the stack.   Much better to use a `#define` or an `enum` to define those values.  Then the value (in general) gets buried in the actual code, where it cannot be `accidentally` modified (as such action would result in a seg fault event.

Comment: the line beginning with: `printf ("Please enter` is randomly indented.  Such random indents make the code much more difficult to read/understand/debug/maintain

Comment: this line: `int ratingCounters[RESPONSE_VALUES] = { 0 };` allows for 10 respondents.  The line should be: `int ratingCounters[MAX_RESPONDANTS] = { 0 };

Comment: the `for()` statement has three parameters.  1) initializer 2) condition 3) step.   This line: `for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < MAX_RESPONDANTS)` is missing the `step`.  Suggest: `for ( loopCount = 0; loopCount < MAX_RESPONDANTS; loopCount++ )

Comment: this line: `if (value > MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE && value <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE)` excludes MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE from what the user is allowed to enter.  I suspect that is not correct.  Suggest: `if (value >= MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE && value <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE)`

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%d", &value);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (read the `man` page for `scanf` for details.   I.E. never trust the user supplied input, always check the I/O for success, not just for the valid range of the input.

Comment: regarding this line: `else if (value = TERMINATOR)`  This is assigning the value `TERMINATOR` to the variable `value`.  (This is one good reason to always place the literal on the left, as then the compiler would catch the error)  I'm reasonably sure you actually wanted to type: `else if ( TERMINATOR == value )

Comment: the checking for the valid range of the user input AND checking if the user is finished (early) with inputting values needs to be performed INSIDE the `for()` loop, not after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

A macro definition isn't a statement and normally won't have a semicolon at the end.

Macros in C are expanded literally, before any other syntax checking is done.  So when you define

```
#define MAX_RESPONDANTS 20;
#define MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE 0; 
#define MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE 10;
#define TERMINATOR -1;
```

and then write

```
printf ("...", MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE, MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE, TERMINATOR);
```

it gets expanded as

```
printf ("...", 0;, 10;, -1;);
```

which I think you will agree is invalid syntax.

So you should remove the semicolons from your macro definitions:

```
 #define MAX_RESPONDANTS 20
```

(Incidentally, the correct spelling is "respondents".)

I am guessing you probably already got a similar error on the line

```
const int RESPONSE_VALUES = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE - MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE
```

and you "fixed" it by removing the semicolon at the end.  But this is expanded as

```
const int RESPONSE_VALUES = 10; - 0;
```

`MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE` isn't actually used in computing the value assigned to `RESPONSE_VALUES`; it's appearing in its own statement, which says "Compute the negative of 0 and then don't do anything with it."

Bonus bugs:

- `ratingCounters` is of size `RESPONSE_VALUES`, which in this case is 10, but you store `MAX_RESPONDANTS` values in it, which is 20.
- In the line `printf("response is","%d" ,RESPONSE_VALUES);` the first two arguments should be a single string.  As it stands the line will just print `response is`.
- In the line `else if (value = TERMINATOR)` you almost certainly mean `==` instead.

Comment: Thanks! i am stuck getting this error out of RESPONSE_VALUES on both lines       for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < MAX_RESPONDENTS)
    {
        scanf("%d", &value);
        ratingCounters[loopCount] = value;    
    }
    printf("response is %s\n", RESPONSE_VALUES);
   
    if (value > MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE && value <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE)
    {
            printf("response is %s\n",RESPONSE_VALUES);
    }
up in the #define how exactly do i get the math in the macros ect : (RESPONSE_VALUES = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE - MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE) I fixed a bunch of the other errors but this stumped me.

Comment: MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE isn't actually used in computing the value assigned to RESPONSE_VALUES; it's appearing in its own statement, which says "Compute the negative of 0 and then don't do anything with it."     how would I get them to subtract

Comment: @Cboehm: The fact that it doesn't subtract is caused by the extra semicolon in the macro definition.  After you remove the semicolon, `RESPONSE_VALUES = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE - MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE;` will be correct.

Comment: please place edits to the question in the text of the question, not as comments

Answer (score 0):

The posted code, as noted in the comments to the question, has lots of problems.

The following code corrects those problems and several others

```
//#include <stdlib.h> -- not needed
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()

// notice no trailing `;` and surrounded by parens
#define MAX_RESPONDANTS    (20)
#define MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE (0)
#define MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE (10)
#define TERMINATOR         (-1)

int main(void)
{
    // -- not needed statement
    //const int RESPONSE_VALUES = MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE - MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE

    int value;
    int loopCount;

    // enter rating 1-10
    int ratingCounters[MAX_RESPONDANTS] = { 0 };

    // loopCount, responses[MAX_RESPONDANTS]; value;

    // corrected `for()` statement for all 3 parameters
    for (loopCount = 0; loopCount < MAX_RESPONDANTS; loopCount++)
    {
        // prompt user for each input value
        printf ("Please enter a value in range %d ... %d."
                " Use %d to end input: \n    ",
            MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE,
            MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE,
            TERMINATOR);

        // check for success
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &value) )
        {
            loopCount--; // adjust for `for` loop increment
            continue;
        }

        if ( TERMINATOR == value )
        {
            break;
        }

        // only check for range after checking for exit
        if (value >= MIN_RESPONSE_VALUE && value <= MAX_RESPONSE_VALUE)
        {
            printf( "response is: %d", value );
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Outside valid range. Please input another number.\n");
            loopCount--; // adjust for `for` loop increment
            continue;
        }

        // got a good value so save it
        ratingCounters[loopCount] = value;
    } // end for loop

    printf("\n\nRating Number of Responses\n");
    printf("------ --------------------\n");

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: notice the handling of a call to `scanf()` returning other than a success indication is buggy and suggest 1) clearing all the stdin characters 2) tell the user of the problem 3) then either exit the program or loop as the current answer is doing.

Comment: the output is not in chart form. how do  I make the output to not print the "enter value from.. everytime and print a chart after

Comment: @Cboehm, the question does not present the format of the chart nor the content of the chart, so that feature needs to be designed/implemented by you.  however to have the prompt only be displayed to the user once, move the printf() for the prompt to before that `for()` statement rather than after the `for()` statement.